# I get an "Inconsistent Accessibility" error

Tags: c#, structuremap

```
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private int salary;
    private List<IEmployee> subordinates;

    public void addEmployee(String name, String department, int salary)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void addSubordinate(IEmployee e)
    {
        subordinates.add(e);
    }

interface IEmployee
{
    void addEmployee(String name, String department, int salary);
    String getEmployeeInfo();
    void addSubordinate(IEmployee e);
}

public void If_We_Add_Alan_As_Johns_Subordinate_We_SHould_get_that()
{
        ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
        {
            x.For<IEmployee>().Use<Employee>();
        });
        var DairyManager = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IEmployee>();
        var Cashier = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IEmployee>();

        Cashier.addEmployee("Alan", "cashier", 1000);
        DairyManager.addEmployee("John", "CEO", 10000);
        DairyManager.addSubordinate(Cashier);
```

The error says :

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type `IEmployee` is less accessible than method `Employee.addSubordinate(Supermarket.IEmployee)`...

Answer (score 4):

You have not provided an access modifier for your interface:

```
interface IEmployee
```

Therefore, [the default (implied) access modifier is `internal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx#Anchor_2).  Just add `public`, like this:

```
public interface IEmployee
```

Answer (score 2):

You should mark the interface as public.

```
public interface IEmployee
```

Since the access modifier of `Employee` is public the same should hold for the `interfaces` that `Employee` implements.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an accessibity modifier to your interface:

```
public interface IEmployee
```

This will fix the error.